# TPL Dataflow not PropagateCompletion not working with predicated linkTos

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

The following unit test never completes. Why?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestFlow()
    {

        var transform1 = new TransformBlock<string, string>(async (s) =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            return s;
        });

        var transform2 = new TransformBlock<string, string>(async (s) =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            return s;
        },new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {

        });

        transform1.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<string>(), new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }, s => s == null);
        transform1.LinkTo(transform2, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true },s => s != null);


        transform1.Post("hello");
        transform1.Post(null);
        transform1.Post("world");

        transform1.Complete();
       // await transform2.Completion;

        while (!transform2.Completion.IsCompleted)
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second flow needs to be emptied for it to complete:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestFlow()
    {

        var transform1 = new TransformBlock<string, string>(async (s) =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            return s;
        });

        var transform2 = new TransformBlock<string, string>(async (s) =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            return s;
        },new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {

        });

        transform1.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<string>(), new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }, s => s == null);
        transform1.LinkTo(transform2, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true },s => s != null);
        transform2.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<string>());

        transform1.Post("hello");
        transform1.Post(null);
        transform1.Post("world");

        transform1.Complete();
       // await transform2.Completion;

        while (!transform2.Completion.IsCompleted)
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
```